# Highlight a prompt with the listings package

Tags: listings, highlighting

I use the `listings` package to typeset a series of commands in the language Octave (a free clone of Matlab) in my lecture notes. Most of the command lines look like this:

```
octave:1> A=eye(4)
A =

Diagonal Matrix

   1   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0
   0   0   1   0
   0   0   0   1

octave:2> det(A)
ans =  1
octave:3>
```

As you can see, each command is prefixed by a prompt in the form `octave:N>`, where `N` is the number of the command in the session (may have more than one character). I do not skip this prompt because I want my notes to look exactly like the students' screens. Output lines have no prefix.

I would like this command prefix to be formatted in a different color (grayed out, to mean that it is not as important as what follows).

How can I do that with `listings`? In the manual I find only an option `gobble` to ignore the first *k* characters of every line, but this does not work in my case since only some lines have this prefix.

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Comment: @Jubobs thanks, looks cool. Any reason why this is a separate package and not included natively in `listings`?

Comment: That's a good question that I probably should have addressed in the documentation... The main reason is that `matlab-prettifier` actually does quite a lot behind the scenes (to keep track of the context); I'm not sure the maintainer of `listings` would have accepted it as a patch.

Comment: Off topic here, but people landing here may be actually looking for [How can I automatically prepend a prompt (e.g. $) to each line of a listing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/220790/61949).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this what you want?

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
\lstset{
    language=Octave,
    moredelim=[s][\color{gray}]{octave:}{>}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
octave:1> A=eye(4)
A =

Diagonal Matrix

   1   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0
   0   0   1   0
   0   0   0   1

octave:2> det(A)
ans =  1
octave:3>
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Output of posted code]

### `moredelim`

The `moredelim` key defines new delimiters that are used to format text manually between them. In this case the delimiters are `octave:` and `>` and they are not thrown away (that would happen if you use `[is]` instead of `[s]`).
Confer to manual section 3.3 and 4.5 to read more about the use of delimiters.