# How can I automatically prepend a prompt (e.g. $) to each line of a listing?

Tags: formatting, listings

I have something that looks as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{shellsession}[1][]
{\lstset{language=bash,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    numbers=none,
    #1
  }}
{}

\begin{document}
\begin{shellsession}
  first line
  second line
  third line
\end{shellsession}
\end{document}
```

This gives me the following output:

[image: basic output]

No surprises there, but I'm wondering whether there is a way to prepend a character to each line. Just to be clear, the output I'd like to get is

```
$ first line
$ second line
$ third line
```

Comment: You might abuse line numbers, defining `\thelstnumber` to produce `\texttt{\$}`, but why not adding `$` to the lines?

Comment: I don't really mind adding the `$` myself. I was just thinking, if there is a way to do it, I would take advantage of it. I don't think I will abuse the line numbers. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Whatever editor you are using probably has a "column editor" mode, that lets you type the same text in a column of the text file... you might look into that, if you are going to do it manually

Comment: @darthbirth: I'm using emacs. So I can easily edit multiple lines. Part of the issue in this case is that emacs thinks that I am still in math mode because of the uneven number of `$` within the file. So it gives me a false error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can prepend something to every "real" line (i.e. not a line created by `listings`'s `breaklines` option) via a `listings` hook called `EveryPar`.

Note that, because `listings` hooks are global, some precautions must be taken if you're typesetting code in multiple `listings` languages but you only want to prepend stuff to lines of listings in a subset of those languages (only one, `bash`, here).

Also, be aware that, without using any countermeasures, e.g.

- `listings`'s `gobble` option (see the bottom of section 4.4 in the [`listings` manual](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf))
- Martin Scharrer's [`lstautogobble`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/lstaddons) package, or
- my experimental [`lstautodedent`](https://github.com/Jubobs/lstautodedent) package,

any indentation present in your `listing` environment will be typeset in the output; this may end up "pushing" your listing to the right, which is undesirable.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter

% define custom macro that expands to the language name
% (for comparison purposes)
\newcommand\langname@bash{}
\def\langname@bash{bash}

% define custom prompt
\newcommand\prompt@bash{\$\ }

% define a macro (initially empty) and insert it at the beginning
% of every paragraph
\newcommand\addedToEveryPar@bash{}
\lst@AddToHook{EveryPar}{\addedToEveryPar@bash}

% redefine the macro by the custom prompt, but only if the language in use
% be `bash'
\lst@AddToHook{PreInit}{%
  \ifx\lst@language\langname@bash%
    \let\addedToEveryPar@bash\prompt@bash%
  \fi
}

\makeatother


\lstnewenvironment{shellsession}[1][]
{\lstset{language=bash,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    numbers=none,
    #1
  }}
{}

\begin{document}
\begin{shellsession}
first line
second line
third line
\end{shellsession}

% just to check that your prompt doesn't find its way into unrelated language...
% (code taken from http://stackoverflow.com/a/14560801/2541573)
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, basicstyle=\ttfamily]
def memo(f):
    cache = {}
    def memoized(n):
        nonlocal cache
        if n not in cache:
            cache[n] = f(n)
        return cache[n]
    return memoized
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```