# How would you typeset this type of programming documentation?

Tags: sectioning, listings, indentation, automation

Consider, for example, [this pdf document](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) which defines the standard for the C programming language. The description of the library functions follows a fixed structure composed of three sections, as shown in the picture below: *synopsis*, *description* and *returns* with numbered paragraphs.

[image: Description of an example function]

To reproduce this structure, I would:

1. Define a subsection (or subsubsection) heading with no numbering and bold title.
2. Use the package `listings` to typeset the synopsis.
3. I don't know how to typeset the paragraph numbers in the margins, but for my specific document I'm not interested in this feature.

According to the above plan, here is a working code which reproduces the given example page (without paragraph numbering to which I'm not interested):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listings}

\renewcommand{\ttfamily}{\usefont{T1}{lmtt}{b}{n}}
\newcommand{\func}[1]{\texttt{#1}}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}

\begin{document}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,tabsize=8}

\section{The \func{rand} function}
\subsection{Synopsis}
\begin{lstlisting}
    #include <stdlib.h>
    int rand(void);
\end{lstlisting}

\subsection{Description}
The \func{rand} function computes a sequence of pseudo-random integers in the range 0 to \func{RAND\_MAX}.

The \func{rand} function is not required to avoid data races with other calls to pseudo-random sequence generation functions. The implementation shall behave as if no library function calls the rand function.

\subsection{Returns}
The \func{rand} function returns a pseudo-random integer.
\subsection{Environmental limits}
The value of the \func{RAND\_MAX} macro shall be at least 32767.
\end{document}
```

The above code yields:

[image: Rendered code]

This result is ok for me, but I'm wondering:

**If you were to write a manual for a library of functions, which has from a few to many sections similar to that above, with the same sequence of subsections and with the same indentation of the code (here realized with a tab character), would you do it in a different, maybe better, way?**

In the above, *better* might mean by defining an environment (e.g. a list) with a parameter for the code and items which generate the correct sequence of headings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You write

> [...] would you do it in a different, maybe better, way? [...] *better* might mean by defining an environment (e.g. a list) with a parameter for the code and items which generate the correct sequence of headings.

### Make your life easier

Strive for **automation**, **consistency**, and **maintainability**. (Note that those desiderata are all a bit intertwined and not strictly independent.) Here are some tips.

1. You should define an environment (called `fun` below) for typesetting the entire section dedicated to a function. This environment should

   - accept one mandatory argument, corresponding to the name of the function of interest, and define a macro for easily typesetting the function's name;
   - typeset the section heading;
   - define a number of "subenvironments" for *Description*, *Returns*, etc. that typeset the corresponding subsection headings.

   What's nice about that last point (defining those <del>four</del> three environments *within* the `fun` environment, as opposed to globally) is that it provides some **encapsulation**, insofar as those environments can only be invoked *within* a `fun` environment. If, for instance, you try to write

   ```
   \begin{fundesc}
   ...
   \end{fundesc}
   ```

   outside a `fun` environment (where it wouldn't make sense), you will get a compilation error. This prevents you from typesetting stuff where it doesn't belong.

   **Edit**: Unfortunately, `listings` mechanism for defining a custom environment (`\lstnewenvironment`) does so at the *global* scope; therefore, encapsulation is not possible for the environment dedicated to synopses.
2. Without countermeasures, any indentation inside an `lstlisting` environment is typeset *verbatim* in the output. See my remark in [How can I automatically prepend a prompt (e.g. $) to each line of a listing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220790/how-can-i-automatically-prepend-a-prompt-e-g-to-each-line-of-a-listing/220799#220799).

   To free yourself from inconsistent indentation in the input, you should use either Martin Scharrer's [`lstautogobble`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/lstaddons) package or my experimental [`lstautodedent`](https://github.com/Jubobs/lstautodedent) package, and let `listings`'s `xleftmargin` key take care of listings' left margin for you:

   ```
   \usepackage{lstautodedent}
   %...
   \lstset{
     %...
     autodedent,
     xleftmargin = 4em, % (for instance)
   }
   ```

### Implementation

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstautodedent}

\renewcommand{\ttfamily}{\usefont{T1}{lmtt}{b}{n}}
\newcommand{\func}[1]{\texttt{#1}}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}

% `Synopsis' environment
\lstnewenvironment{funsynop}{
  \subsection{Synopsis}
  \lstset{
    basicstyle  = \ttfamily,
    tabsize     = 8,
    autodedent,
    xleftmargin = 4em,
  }%
}{}

% Custom environment for typesetting everything related to a function
\newenvironment{fun}[1]{%
  \newcommand\funname{\func{#1}}
  \section{The \funname{} function}
  % `Description' environment
  \newenvironment{fundesc}{%
    \subsection{Description}
  }{}
  % `Returns' environment
  \newenvironment{funret}{%
    \subsection{Returns}
  }{}
  % `Environmental limits' environment
  \newenvironment{funlim}{%
    \subsection{Environmental limits}
  }{}
}{}


\begin{document}

\begin{fun}{rand}
  \begin{funsynop}
    #include <stdlib.h>
    int rand(void);
  \end{funsynop}
  %
  \begin{fundesc}
    The \funname{} function computes a sequence of pseudo-random integers
    in the range 0 to \func{RAND\_MAX}.

    The \funname{} function is not required to avoid data races with other calls
    to pseudo-random sequence generation functions.
    The implementation shall behave as if no library function calls the
  \funname{} function.
  \end{fundesc}
  %
  \begin{funret}
    The \funname{} function returns a pseudo-random integer.
  \end{funret}
  %
  \begin{funlim}
    The value of the \func{RAND\_MAX} macro shall be at least 32767.
  \end{funlim}
\end{fun}

\begin{fun}{foo}
  \begin{funsynop}
               foo = foo : foos  <--- messed up indentation
                                      (but output is fine)
  \end{funsynop}
  %
  \begin{fundesc}
    The \funname{} function blah blah blah
  \end{fundesc}
  %
  \begin{funret}
    The \funname{} function returns a foo.
  \end{funret}
  %
  \begin{funlim}
    The \funname{} function is limited to \func{bar}.
  \end{funlim}
\end{fun}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### Possible improvements

- Enforce the order in which the four "subenvironments" are meant to appear.
- (If needed) Throw a compilation error if one or more of those "subenvironments" are missing.

Comment: But this will give a compilation error if you try to use the environment `fun` more than once within the same document.

Comment: @cfr Yes, sorry about that. Fixed. Unfortunately, though, because `\lstnewenvironment` defines a custom listing environment at the global scope, I can't encapsulate my `funsynop` environment.