# Put default text in listings environment

Tags: listings, sourcecode

I want to make a gray box with some code inside but it should already appear a centered tilde followed by a dollar sign. Or how can I use a command inside the environment to obtain certain text like `\newcommand{\prompt}{user@linux:\~\$}`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec,listings,color}
\definecolor{verbgray}{gray}{0.9}
\newfontfamily\ubuntumono{Ubuntu Mono}
\lstnewenvironment{sh}{
  \lstset{backgroundcolor=\color{verbgray},
  frame=single,
  framerule=1pt,
  basicstyle=\ubuntumono,
  columns=fullflexible}}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{sh}
user@linux:(centered tilde)$
\end{sh}
\end{document}
```

This must be built with XeLaTeX for the fontspec package.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: related: [How can I automatically prepend a prompt (e.g. $) to each line of a listing?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220790/how-can-i-automatically-prepend-a-prompt-e-g-to-each-line-of-a-listing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `etoolbox` package you can patch `\lst@NewLine` similar to my example below. (I removed the dependency on `fontspec` for my tests…):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings,xcolor,etoolbox}
\definecolor{verbgray}{gray}{0.9}

\newcommand*\prompt{}% empty default
\lstnewenvironment{sh}{%
  % redefine bash prompt:
  \renewcommand*\prompt{user@linux:\textasciitilde>\space}%
  \lstset{backgroundcolor=\color{verbgray},
    frame=single,
    framerule=1pt,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    columns=fullflexible
  }%
}{}

% patch \lst@NewLine:
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\lst@NewLine
  {\hbox{}}% search
  {\hbox{}\prompt}% replace
  {}% success
  {}% failure
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{sh}
foo

baz
\end{sh}

% other listings behave as they should:   
\begin{lstlisting}
foo
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

`listings` actually has a hook `OnNewLine` but code added with `\lst@AddToHook{OnNewLine}{<code>}` seems to be placed before the `\par\noindent` in `\lst@NewLine` which means its contents appear at the end of the preceding line which may or may not be a bug (it looks like one to me…).